# C# Object Comparisons

Tags: c#

In C#, is there a way to overload comparison operators such as `==`, `=<` or`>` on a user-defined object?

Similar to how yo can write `"string"=="string"` instead of `"string".Equals("string")`

I know you can define the CompareTo and Equals functions but I was wondering if there was a shortcut.

Comment: You can always [overload the operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for your class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to best implement Equals for custom types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567642/how-to-best-implement-equals-for-custom-types)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is clearly not a duplicate of this question; he's asking how to overload operators, not what sensible implementations of them are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the `==` operators in C# by implementing a function with the following signature in the desired `class`:

`public static bool operator ==(YourClass a, YourClass b) { }`

The same applies to `<=` and `>` operators.

By overriding `==` you must also override `!=`, and is recommended to overload the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` functions.

For more info, read:

[Operator Overloading Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Link only answers are not considered acceptable on Stack Overflow.  If you're going to post links to content you should also explain the link, quote a relevant section, and or summarize enough of the content such that the question is answered entirely within your post and following the link is just optional, not required to see the solution.

Comment: @Servy Thanks! I didn't know. I'll make up to it!

Answer (score 4):

Simple example:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(Foo first, Foo second)
    {
        return first.Id == second.Id;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo first, Foo second)
    {
        return first.Id != second.Id;
    }
}
```

You should also override Equals and GetHashCode