# Nunit Assert List<SomeObject> contains unique values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, assert, assertion

Say we have a class

```
class A
{
int num;
string str;
// more methods and data members
}
```

In a nunit test, how can we do something in the lines of

```
List<A> listA = GetUniqueValueList();
CollectionAssert.AllItemsAreUnique(listA, "ListA items should be unique.");
```

As far as I understand, the AllItemsAreUniqe works for lists with value types only. Also this test doesn't fail if say two A objects have exact same members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality is determined by the implementation of [`.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can override. For a complex type this will not work out-of-the-box the way you envision it so you have to override it to account for your vision of "equality".

- [Guidelines for Overloading Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)
- [Implementing the Equals method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [How to best implement Equals for custom types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567642/how-to-best-implement-equals-for-custom-types)

Comment: so you mean I override Equals in Class A to return false if say a.Num != b.Num ?
This will work?

Comment: What if I do not own the class? Just a curiosity. Although I have access, it is advisable not to modify it.

Comment: Sometimes you have the possibility to also specify an `IEqualityComparer<T>` which acts like an external `.Equals()` method, but `AllItemsAreUnique` does not provide that. If you don't want to modify the class then you *could* write a wrapper class around that and implement `.Equals()` there and use the public members while holding your class `A` as a member. But that's getting  quite complex for little gain. Ideally every custom class should have a `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()` implementation anyway so definitely look into changing your class `A`.