# How does ObjectCollection.Add() works

Tags: c#, winforms

Does ObjectCollection.Add(item) call item.Equals()?
Got a `CheckedListBox` on a `Form`, and tried to add some items. But I found when `CheckedListBox.Items.Add(item)` was called, it would call `item.Equals()`. 
Also, I found `item.GetHashCode()` was called, too. Very confused about why did it happen.
Code are as below.

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();//Person is a customer class for test.
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "张三", Id = "201411580572", Gender = "Male" });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "李四", Id = "201411580573", Gender = "Male" });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "王武", Id = "201411580574", Gender = "Male" });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "赵柳", Id = "201411580575", Gender = "Male" });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "张飞", Id = "201411580576", Gender = "Male" });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "赵云", Id = "201411580577", Gender = "Male" });

cklTest.DisplayMember = "Name";//cklTest is a CheckedListBox.

people.ForEach(p => cklTest.Items.Add(p));
```

**Edit**:

[callstack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBnce.jpg)

Comment: How did you find out that equals was called?

Comment: databinding likely calls those methods to determine what to display to the user. it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Why don't you just use AddRange() instead of ForEach method?

Comment: @preciousbetine I override the `Equals()` of the test-class. And it throwed error at the method.

Comment: Could you check if the `Sorted` property of your CheckedListBox is set to true?

Comment: @jdweng I used to try the `AddRange()` method but it throwed error, and I thought maybe `Add()` would work well.

Comment: The [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListBox.cs,0d4081dfd8f378bb,references) shows that it needs to find the insert-position if the `ListControl` is sorted

Comment: @KevinGosse It is set false.

Comment: Alternatively, you can uncheck `Enable Just My Code` in the Visual Studio options (Tools -> Options -> Debugging), then put a breakpoint in your `Equals` method and check the callstack. This way we'll know exactly where it comes from

Comment: @KevinGosse I put a picture in the question content.

Comment: So you are updating `CheckedListBox` items and confused as to why some [specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.objectcollection) to that control collection calls some methods. Why would you want to know this? I am just curious what possible problem is lying behind such findings..

Comment: You tried this : cklTest.Items.AddRange(people);

Comment: Can you try setting `FormattingEnabled` to false on your CheckedListBox?

Comment: @jdweng I tried it at very beginning, and it also called the `Equals()` method.

Comment: @KevinGosse Amazing, it now will not call the `Equals()` method. Thank you so much. So, it will call these methods id this property is set true?

Comment: Gonna write a short explanation

Comment: I don't understand why this question got 3 times downvoted and is going to be be closed because it "must include desired behaviour...". OP noticed that his `Equals` is called when he adds items to a `CheckedListBox`. He wants to understand it and the answer isn't obvious(especially because [`Sorted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_Sorted) is `false`), so doesn't deserve downvotes, imo. The desired behavior is obviously that `Equals` is _not_ called.

Comment: @Sinatr Well, in this case,for example,  the `Equals()` method was very simple, `return Id==(obj as Person).Id;`. And it throwed `NullReferenceException`. So,  if I know when and why it calls this method, I can get the code optimized to avoid this.

Comment: @ZelgiusLiu, that problem is [much easier to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/567642/1997232), simply fix your implementation. For any method receiving `object` parameter you have to expect a failed cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callstack shows that the call comes from `Formatter.FormatObject` which in turn calls `Formatter.IsNullData`.

[The code of `IsNullData`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Formatter.cs,447) is:

```
public static bool IsNullData(object value, object dataSourceNullValue) {
    return value == null ||
           value == System.DBNull.Value ||
           Object.Equals(value, NullData(value.GetType(), dataSourceNullValue));
}
```

We see the call to `Object.Equals` to check if your object is equal to `dataSourceNullValue` (a custom value to represent null data). Interestingly, in this context dataSourceNullValue is `DBNull.Value`, therefore the check is redundant with the one above. But nothing you can do about that.

In case you don't want Equals to be called on this codepath, you can workaround by setting `FormattingEnabled` to false. This will cause the CheckedListBox to use [an alternative way](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,559) to format your object:

```
if (!formattingEnabled) {

    // Microsoft gave his blessing to this RTM breaking change
    if (item == null) {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    item = FilterItemOnProperty(item, displayMember.BindingField);
    return (item != null) ? Convert.ToString(item, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) : "";
}
```