# C# linq Intersect override for complex object

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two objects (dummy code)

```
var students = new List<Student>();  
var girl = new Student() { Name = "Simran", StudentId = 4 };  
var sameGirl = new Student() { Name = "Norman", StudentId = 4 };
```

I wanted to check if these two objects are the same using the `Intersect` method but to my understanding `Intersect` uses `Equals` under the hood so these two objects will evaluate to false, I don't really know how to override the `Equals` or `Intersect` methods, but in essence, I want to check if the Ids of the objects are the same. Can the `Equals` or `Intersect` method be overridden to evaluate a part of the object, not the whole object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to best implement Equals for custom types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567642/how-to-best-implement-equals-for-custom-types)

Comment: Do you mean Intersect instead of Intercept?

Comment: i meant intersect my apologies

Comment: Note that `Enumerable.Intersect` has an overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer` so you could pass that to override just the calls to `Intersect`. You can not use `Intersect` with EF Core - why did you tag with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thank you all for your help, you pointed me out in the right direction, I didn't really understand how to override the equals or the comparer

   public class fooComparer<T> : IEqualityCmparer<T> where T :notnull
    {
    public book Equals(T? x, T? y)
    {
    return x?.studentId == y?.studentId && x!= null
    }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
    return $"{obj.StudentId}
    _{obj.Name}".GetHashCode():}}
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon your choice. You can override the Equals method and just compare only required properties and on the basis of comparison, return true or false.

So, implement `IComparer` and override the `Equals` method. Only include `StudentId` of the source and target for comparison. Would that fulfill your requirement?

Comment: Note, if you override `Equals` you should also override `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Exactly this method is very important. GetHashCode will confirm that it includes only the specified properties for comparison.